# Accuracy of QPE using histogram fit

Tags: quantum-phase-estimation

In regular QPE, accuracy is $1/2^n$, where $n$ is estimation register size, and it is done with few shots and depth as $O(2^n)$ (total cost of $O(2^n*NumShots))=2^n=1/resolution$).

I thought of the fact that by an exact fit of QPE (with small estimation register size $n$) output that looks like a "sinc" with the solution as the center of that sinc, one can find the phase with better accuracy than $1/2^n$ assuming enough $NumShots$, the accuracy will be something like $O(1/(2^n*\sqrt{NumShots})))$ with total cost of $O(2^n*NumShots))=O(NumShots))=1/resolution^2$. (Notice amount of data is exponential only in the resolution and not in the entire problem/molecule/etc size)

This leads to the fact it might be wrong to do the second way, which eliminates the quantum advantage as it behaves like the complexity of a classical approach to solve the problem.

BUT - I wonder what are the classical alternatives? Perhaps there are still use cases where it can be better to go the second way than solving classically? It is more natural to give Hamiltonian to Quantum Computer, rather than solving classically.

I will be happy for an answer that knows concrete classical alternatives and their dis/advantage to this fit approach